# Flask HTTPException being swallowed

Tags: python, exception, flask, werkzeug

When declaring a function with `before_request` Flask is swallowing HTTPExceptions and not propagating them:

```
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.before_request
def f():
    raise HTTPException("This is not propagated")

@app.route('/')
def test():
    return 'This is a view'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The console shows no Exception:

```
$ python flask_test1.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2016 15:01:31] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

The Browser shows:

```
Unknown Error

This is not propagated
```

Is there a way to force it ? A setting I need to specify, or should I interface Werkzeug HTTPExceptions and raise custom made Exceptions ?

Comment: So you see *"This is a view"* when you browse to that endpoint? Or do you get an HTTP error code/some error page (which is the expected behaviour)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe edited

Comment: And why isn't that the outcome that you were expecting? That's what's supposed to happen! See http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/exceptions/

Answer (score -1):

The likely reason isn't that you aren't supposed to raise `HTTPException` itself. `HTTPException` is itself supposed to be a *base class* for other exceptions, such as `BadRequest` or `NotFound`.

Since `HTTPException` *has no HTTP code to return*, no such code is logged or sent to the user. If you raise `NotFound`, `BadRequest`, or any of the subclasses of HTTPException, those work fine, at least in Flask 0.11:

```
from werkzeug.exceptions import BadRequest
@app.before_request
def f():
    raise BadRequest("This is definitely propagated")
```

Comment: But that will be propagated *in exactly the same way*, appearing as a non-2xx return in the browser rather than crashing the program and showing a traceback. The issue here isn't the use of `HTTPException`, is that the OP doesn't understand how these errors are supposed to work.